# Overloading Type-Cast in c++

Tags: c++

I want to understand how typecast-overloading works. For my question, I want to know

1. The thing I'm trying to do is it possible?
2. If yes, then how?

I want the user to be able to pass a `vector<float>` to a function. This function is implemented in such a way that its parameter is a wrapper class around `vector<float>`.

Can typecast-overloading help in such a case? (automatically convert `vector<float>` into `Layer`)
or do we have to use some complicated templated function?

```
// ---------- someFile.cpp ------------
class Layer {
    vector<float> l;
  public:
    friend void process (const Layer& someLayer);
}
// ---------- main.cpp ------------
int main() {
    vector<float> vec = {1.0, 1.5, 2.0};
    process(vec);
}
```

Comment: There are two equivalent ways to add a conversion: to a type (with a conversion constructor) and from a type (with a conversion operator). The first one was answered. For the second way the `operator Layer` would have to be added to the `std::vector` class, which is not feasible, but could be for other cases, where you convert *from* your own class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that's needed is a non-explicit constructor taking the correct argument (a so-called conversion constructor):

```
class Layer {
    vector<float> l;

public:
    Layer(vector<float> const& v);
};
```

Now the compiler will be able to do implicit conversions from `vector<float>` to `Layer`.

Note that it's usually not recommended to have such conversion constructors being non-explicit (not declared using the `explicit` keyword), because sometimes implicit conversions might be unexpected and not wanted.

Comment: Wow, this idea of conversion constructor is new to me. Thank You!

Comment: can you also explain why did you choose to write the `const` keyword after the data type? I know of `const vector<float>` but not of `vector<float>const`?

Comment: @MeharjeetSingh `const type&` and `type const&` means the same thing. It's my personal preference to think of it as "a reference to a constant vector of floats" instead of "a reference to a vector of floats that is constant".